# Reading and outputting unicode in C

Tags: c

```
FILE * f = fopen("filename", "r");
int c;

while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c\n", c);
}
```

Hello, I have searched for a whole hour, found many wise dissertations on Unicode, but no answer to this simple question:

what would be the shortest equivalent to these four lines, that can manage UTF8, on Linux using gcc and bash.

Thank you

Comment: Does your terminal understand UTF8/unicode? If it doesn't you won't notice any difference.

Comment: UTF-8? UTF-16? UTF-32? Wide character? If wide characters, on what operating system and with what compiler?

Comment: Hello, thank you, I edited to answer your questions.

Comment: Have you tried this code with no changes? What were the results? Also, what does bash have to to with it?

Comment: I suggest you look into the [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) library.

Comment: First of all, thank you. Secondly this is a first 'serious' assignment from a first year C course, whose aim is to build a text indexer. Is there definitely no few-liner that will do the trick? I doubt it is intended for us to use a lib. On the other hand, the proposed solution (fgets) sometimes works on non-ascii, sometimes not, so it is hardly a good solution.

Comment: You need to read more about [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). An UTF-8 character can be anything from one to six characters. So if the first byte you read have a specific bit-pattern, then you need to read another character, and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work, given your system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main() {
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_GB.UTF-8");
   FILE * f = fopen("filename", "r");
   wint_t c;

   while((c = fgetwc(f)) != WEOF) {
      wprintf(L"%lc\n", c);
   }
}
```

The problem with your original code is that C doesn't realise (or care) that the characters are multibyte, and so your multibyte characters will be corrupted by the `\n` between each of the bytes. With this version, a character is treated as UTF-8, and so `%lc` now may represent as many as 6 actual bytes, which are guaranteed to be output correctly. If the input has any ASCII, it'll simply use one byte per character as previously (since ASCII is compatible with UTF-8).

`strace` is always useful for debugging things like this. As an example, if the file contains just `££` (£ has the UTF-8 sequence \302\243). Your version produces:

```
write(1, "\302\n\243\n\302\n\243\n\n\n", 10) = 10
```

And mine,

```
write(1, "\302\243\n\302\243\n", 6)     = 6
```

Note that once you read or write to a stream (including `stdout`) it is set to either byte or wide orientation, and you will need to re-open the stream if you want to change it. So for example, if you wanted to read the UTF-8 file, but leave `stdout` as byte orientated, you could replace the `wprintf` with:

```
  printf("%lc\n", c);
```

This involves extra code in the background (to convert the formats), but provides better compatibility with other code that expect a byte stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps tremendously.

Comment: And thanks once more. I won't be pushing libraries to the general public anytime soon, but this program now works.

Comment: @pouzzler - glad it helped. Unicode handling is still (relatively) new in C, and there's not a lot of good help around

Comment: This breaks a string into programmer-perceived characters (codepoints), it can break a user-perceived character (e.g: স্ক → স + BENGALI SIGN VIRAMA + ক) into several characters. To properly divide a text in user-perceived characters, you need something like ICU's BreakIterator.